# system of ODEs in matrix form

Tags: numpy, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to figure out how to solve and plot the system dx/dt = Ax for a 2x2 matrix A. I don't really know how to do this. The code I currently have is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def sys(x, t, A):
    x1, x2 = x    
    return [A @ x]

A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])


x0 = np.array([[1], [2]])

t = np.linspace(0, 100, 10000)

sol = odeint(sys, x0, t, A)

ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(t, sol)
plt.show()
```

The error message is:

```
output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
odepack.error: Extra arguments must be in a tuple.
```

Help on how to make this code work correctly would be very much appreciated. Please note, I am very new to coding, let alone coding differential equations.
Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the other arguments in a tuple. Something like this:

```py
sol = odeint(sys, x0, t, args=(A,))
```

See the [documentation on scipy.integrate.odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).

Comment: Thank you. Upon implementing your suggestion, the additional error saying the initial condition passed to the function sys must be one-dimensional. After some research I found I can change my function to                                                                                 
 def sys(x, t, A):
    x1, x2 = x   
    dxdt = A @ x.reshape(2, 1)
    return np.squeeze(np.asarray(dxdt))                                                                                      which seemed to work just fine.

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Providing the correct `args`, and `x` shape are two of the most common problems with using `scipy` functions like this.  Close attention to the docs is important,